# How to fix "Hashmap error: " error in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap

I want to use hashmap in C++ in Ubuntu 18.04. Butthis error makes me confusing.

I want to use hashmap in C++ in Ubuntu 18.04. Butthis error makes me confusing.

> The complete error code is "Hashmap error: no matching function for
>   call to ‘std::map,
>   int>::find(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits
>
> > ::value_type&)"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map> using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "dfsfsdfsf";
    int i = 0, j = 0, ans = 0, leng;
    map<string,int> window;
    leng = s.length();
    for(;j < leng; j++){
        if(window.find(s.at(j)) != window.end()){
            i = max(i, window[s.at(j)])
        }
    }
    return 0; }
```

I do not know what happened. Please someone helps me. ^~^

Answer (score 0):

`std::string::at` returns a reference to a `char`, a single character. Meanwhile `std::map::find` expected a reference to the key type, a `std::string`. There is no implicit conversion from a single character to a string. So you don't give `find` the argument it expected.

A possible workaround is to use `std::basic_string::substr` instead of `at`. This member function returns a string, by value, that holds a substring. You give it a position and how many characters to read. So the immediate fix to your code can be:

```
window.find(s.substr(j,1)) != window.end()
```

Other than that, do note that `std::map` is an **ordered map**. As such it is usually implement by using a self-balancing binary tree. If you don't need order, and indeed want amortized constant lookup time like a hash would provide, you need `std::unordered_map`.